# Simplify $(¬x∨y∨z)∧(x∨¬(y∧z))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I've been asked to construct a proposition based on its truth table. The truth table is:

```
x y z F(x,y,z)  
1 1 1 1  
1 1 0 1  
1 0 1 1  
1 0 0 0  
0 1 1 0  
0 1 0 1  
0 0 1 1  
0 0 0 1
```

I've gone this far with constructing the proposition:
$(x∧¬y∧¬z)∨(¬x∧y∧z) ≡ F$
$¬((x∧¬y∧¬z)∨(¬x∧y∧z)) ≡ T$
$≡(¬(x∧¬y∧¬z))∧(¬(¬x∧y∧z))$
$≡(¬x∨y∨z)∧(x∨¬(y∧z))$

But now I don't know how to proceed. The previous question was about the XOR connective (⊕) so I think the final proposition will also have the XOR connective. I've noticed from the table that $F(x,y,z)$ is false precisely when only one of either $x$ or $(y,z)$ is true, which tells me that the proposition is probably "$x$ not XOR $(y,z)$" but I've tested the proposition $¬(x⊕(y∨z))$ and it does not produce that truth table. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's as simplified as you can get it, though personally I prefer statements in CNF or DNF and find those 'simpler', and so I would stick with:

$$(\neg x\lor y \lor z)\land (x\lor \neg y \lor \neg z)$$

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I guess I was too caught up on trying to include the XOR connective in the expression. It took me a good night's sleep to realize I already had my final answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. You can use your truth table and observe that $F(x,y,z) = 0$ if and only if $y = z = \neg x$.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm so baffled by this question, reading your answer I thought for sure it was going to be $¬x⊕y⊕z$, but it isn't. Thank you for your answer, though!